# Does app build in XamarinStudio 5.1 be compatible with IOS 10?

Tags: xamarin.ios

I've built an app for ios in XS5.1 and its not working in IOS 10. Isn't it compatible?

I have tried several times and i am not able to update to new XS due to some limitations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be more helpful to know about ios10 compatibility.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/introduction-to-ios10/

Answer (score 0):

iOS 10 support requires the latest version of the iOS SDK's that require the latest version of XCode, which requires the latest version of Xamarin Studio.

Comment: iOS 10 support is not the same to "iOS 10 compatibility" that he requires.

Answer (score 0):

In general iOS 10 can run iOS 9 or even older apps without the problem (most apps aren't updated at the time of iOS 10 release so what would happen if most apps wouldn't work on iOS10...?). However you need to test and see if everything is OK and if it is not try to find some workaround, because problems are surely possible.

So it isn't necessary to have the latest Xamarin Studio to make an app that will work on iOS 10.